# How do I ensure I can loop through every enqueued script and CSS?

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, hooks, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'm on a bit of an efficiency drive. To this end, I would like to check all the scripts and CSS that get enqueued on my multisite setup. I plan to check that they are offloaded to public CDNs if available or some other private static site if I have set that up, while also ensuring there are no duplicates.

Where I am currently stuck (aside from wondering if the extra work actually will save load times at all) is what hook I can use to make sure all the enqueing is done when my script kicks in.

What hook or filter should I use for this purpose?

(Feel free to educate me and any future searchers about anything else I/we should know when attempting this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the basics, I have learned that there are two actions to hook - `wp_print_scripts` and `wp_print_styles` which I understand are called just before they are then added to the header.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_list_scripts' );
function my_list_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $enqueued_scripts = array();
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) {
        // do something clever
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_list_styles' );
function my_list_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    $enqueued_styles = array();
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ) {
        // do something clever
    }
}
```